# How to call setState or function inside on amchart pie slice on hit event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using amchart4 piechart. I have created an onClick event in the pie slice. but when I am trying to call this.setState() or any function() inside event it's not working. How to resolve this issue.
her is my code

```
pieSeries.slices.template.events.on("hit", function(ev) {
       //this.disp_model(); 
       this.setState({Visible:true})
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), something like this.

```
pieSeries.slices.template.events.on("hit", (ev) => {
       //this.disp_model(); 
       this.setState({Visible:true})
});
```